# Installation problem in yureka

Tags: micromax-yu-yureka

I cannot click install when selected an app to install in yureka ?( Not in play store,selected through a file manager) I'm sure it is not a touch screen problem.

Comment: disable your screen filter and try installing your app again

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by a security feature of Android, to stop third-party apps trying to overlay or hide the permissions information when an app is trying to be installed.

Apps such as [Lux](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vitocassisi.luxlite), [Screen Filter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.haxor) or any other filter/overlay app will prevent you from being able to click the `Install` button as they are essentially just an overlay, on top of the "Package installer" dialogue screen.

If you disable or turn off the filter whilst installing an app you should be able to click the `Install` button again. Once clicked you can turn the app back on.